# SQL Query Inner Join + extra condition and

Tags: inner-join

I've got 2 tables, Angestelle and LogDocAction. I need everything of both tables if

```
Angestellte.ID = LogDocAction.User_ID
```

but I also need everything of LogDocAction (not of Angestelle) if the User_ID is 0.

I tried this:

```
logAction.Open "SELECT * FROM Angestellte INNER JOIN LogDocAction ON Angestellte.ID = LogDocAction.User_ID OR LogDocAction.User_ID = 0 ORDER BY LogDocAction.time DESC;", userDB, 1, 3
```

But that didn't work like i want. The entries with the User_ID = 0 are taken out 5 times. :/

Why I don't use 2 queries? I need the entries sorted for a table in ASP and don't know how to do it in another way.

Does anyone know how to solve this? 
Greetings!

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
SELECT A.*, L.* 
FROM LogDocAction L
LEFT JOIN Angestellte A ON A.ID = L.User_ID 
WHERE A.ID IS NOT NULL OR L.User_ID = 0 
ORDER BY L.time DESC
```